# JQuery UI Draggable set hitbox different from element or set multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having an Issue that I'm trying to apply draggable to some a popup element of an external library (I can't modify them).

The problem is that, the most outer div of this popup is actually slightly outside it and has 0 height (its an arrow shaped div, its kinda like a dialog balloon), so it doesn't properly works with the containment.

I could just chose the inner element as a selector (which is the actual popup bounding box), but then the arrow element will not move with the popup.

As stated, I can't modify these elements in a way of grouping them togheter (Actually I don't even have access to the source, doing it in developer console), so how can I solve this? I would like to keep using JQuery UI, but if not possible I'm open to alternatives.

I've tried multiple selectors, but it won't move the arrow div :

```
$( ".dialogArrow, #popupDiv" ).draggable({ scroll: false });
```

Example code :

```
<div class="dialogArrow" style="height:0; width: 100%; background: red">I'm the parent but my hitbox is wrong
    <div id="popupDiv" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: green">actual hitbox</div>
    <div>i need to move togheter too</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hvkh7mmq/5/

Comment: Need to see the HTML that you trying to use the selector with and any other relevant code.

Comment: @Twisty I can't post the actual html but I added an example

Comment: I do not see a `titlePane` class in your example. This does not appear to be a complete example.

Comment: @Twisty Removed unecesary parameters...

Comment: Things still do not look correct, like: `<div class=".dialogArrow" style="height:0; width: 100%; background: red">`, did you mean to have it be class `.dialogArrow` or `dialogArrow`?

Comment: @Twisty yes... sorry I don't know much of html

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `handle` option ([demo](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle)). Like so:

```
$(function() {
  $(".dialogArrow").draggable({
    handle: "div#popupDiv",
    scroll: false
  });
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hvkh7mmq/3/

I did not see a point to your selector, since you want to drag the parent element, not assign `.draggable()` to both elements. Since the parent has no render-able HTML, it can't be clicked upon in essence. So using the `handle` option, we can specify something that can be clicked.

**Additional**

If you inspect the element after dragging, you will see something like:

```
<div class="dialogArrow ui-draggable" style="height: 0px; width: 100%; background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: relative; left: 107px; top: 30px;">
  <div id="popupDiv" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: green; cursor: inherit;" class="ui-draggable-handle">actual hitbox</div>
  <div id="other div that needs to move togheter"></div>
</div>
```

The structure is not changed. All 3 elements are moved.

Comment: The issue is not the handle, is the hitbox of the parent element that has no height

Comment: @Mojimi you're not being clear. You stated you wanted to drag `.dialogArrow` and it's content. This will do that. Now, in regards to containement, the issue is that the width of the draggable is 100% of the parent. Hence you will only be able to drag along the Y axis. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5qeve6eo/

Comment: I thought it was clear, in the title it says that I need to set the hitbox different from the selector, or select multiple ones, I'm aware I can only move in the Y axis, that's the problem

Comment: @Mojimi you're not being clear. What element do you want to be the container then? The `body`? Another element?

Comment: The big green one that says "actual hitbox", but if I set it as the selector, the parent div wont move togheter

Comment: That element cannot be the container as that is the element that is being dragged. If you use the code I posted above, with no `containment` option defined, it will default to `document` and allow all 3 elements to be dragged anyplace in the document. So again, it's not clear what the issue is.